# bootstrap multi input file

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I want to use 6 input file in one page, in a vue template
I want that user could upload six files in six different inputs. each input is like this:

```
<div class="form-group">

  <label class="form__label font-size--15 font-w--400">
   {{$t("تصویر جلو کارت ملی")}}
  </label>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">

    <div class="custom-file ">
      <input id="melliCardFront" type="file" class="custom-file-input" @change="processMelliCardFront($event)" />
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="melliCardFront">انتخاب فایل</label>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="file-listing">
    {{ mellicard_front.name }}
    <span class="remove-file" v-show="mellicard_front" v-on:click="removeMelliCardFront()">حذف</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

but when I use this, the `input` files Are arranged from above of page. when I take the `opacity` of `input` file to 1, the page is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRUaI.png)

my problem is that when I click on top of the page, it opens an input file. or in some browsers, it opens instead of other input.how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Am I right that you try to select a file using one of the inputs but it appears to be selected by all the inputs on the page?

Comment: no. for example, i try to select 3rd input, but 6th input is selected